# What is the most elegant way to use svg icons as background?

Tags: css, sass, icons

I'm not a frontend expert and I need just few icons in my app, so I thought instead of relying on huge icon packs like font-awesome (which come with a huge css file), I just code my own icons css. Here is what I cam up with (in scss):

```
$icon-width: 24px;
$icon-height: 24px;
.thumbs-up {
  width: $icon-width;
  height: $icon-height;
  &:before {
    content: "   ";
    background: url(/icons/thumbs-up.svg) no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

And I can simply link use `thumbs-up` in my html like this:

```
> <p class="thumbs-up" id="like"></p>
```

This works fine,   I'm wondering if there are any flaws in this or maybe there are more elegant ways to do so?

Comment: This approach is best if you need just few icons

Answer (score 0):

### Check the Context

It depends on the context. Honestly that's the better approach on your example case.

To choose between CSS or the `IMG` tag you have to ask yourself if it's just purely design or if the image is contextual, if it's a part of the content itself.

If it's merely for design, use CSS. If it's a required context for the page then use the `IMG` tag, the `IMG` tag comes with the `title` and `alt` parameters that will explain the context of the image when the image can't be displayed, helping people with screen readers and search engines crawlers.

There are many other points where both differ but those only explain even more why CSS is better suited for pure design and the `IMG` tag is for contextual images.

#### Extra SVG goodies

SVGs though are XML files and if you embed them on the page (not with the `IMG` tag but actually pasting their XML code inside the html) you can manipulate their elements through CSS and JavaScript.

For example look at [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8), if you hover over their logo on the top left you'll notice that the triangles glow where your mouse points. That's only achievable by embedding the SVG code in the page instead of using CSS or the `IMG` tag.